# How to call back into android code from Youtube IFRAME API

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am loading an embedded youtube player in my android webview as follows:

```
void loadYTVideoInWebView(String code) {
String frameVideo = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\n" +
        "        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>\n" +
        "                var player;\n" +
        "        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\n" +
        "        {player=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}\n" +
        "        function onPlayerReady(event){player.playVideo();}\n" +
        "        </script>\n" +
        "        <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='400' height='360'\n" +
        "        src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+code+"?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>\n" +
        "        </body></html>";
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.youtube.com", frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8", null);}
```

Once the video finishes playing, I want to send a notification to the Android code. I know that we can detect the video end in the Javascript using something like:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {          
            alert('done');
        }
    }
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to call back into the android code from here.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this answer will not directly solve your issue with IFRAME API but, if you want to use Android in your application, then try to consider the [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) instead of IFRAME API.

The YouTube Android Player API enables you to incorporate video playback functionality into your Android applications. The API defines methods for loading and playing YouTube videos (and playlists) and for customizing and controlling the video playback experience.

You can also register event listeners to get callbacks for certain events, such as the player loading a video or the player state changing. Finally, the API has helper functionality to support orientation changes as well as transitions to fullscreen playback.

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this API. However I am not sure if it allows users to embed the player in a webview. I think they load the video in their custom view or fragment. Also as much as possible I wanted to do this without relying on external libraries. I hope there is another way, otherwise I will try to use this.

Comment: I was able to use this API to create a player and control it from my Android code. Thanks.